# What is the purpose of [ x"$1" != x"" ]?

Tags: bash, shell, sh, dash-shell

What is the purpose of `[ x"$1" != x"" ]`?

Looking through xdg-screensaver, the very first command that is run:

```
[ x"$1" != x"" ] || exit_failure_syntax
```

The shebang is `#!/bin/sh` (which is dash for me).

I have found similar syntax in other old shell scripts... What is the purpose of this?

I guess there is an old habit to use || rather than && to exit... Perhaps something to do with `set -e`. But why not just use something like `[ -n "$1" ] || exit_failure_syntax`, `-z`, `$# -ne 0`, etc...

As I mentioned, I've seen this strange `x"$var" = x""` stuff before. Why would anyone do this?

Comment: See http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/shell_script_mistakes.html

Comment: It's mainly done because the older shells do not have the options `-z`, `-n` or the older `[` (test) command couldn't handle empty strings. So you'll only them in scripts that are very old (probably 25 yrs old or more) or people carry on use the same method to this day. There's no reason to use them in modern shells.

Comment: Thanks @BlueMoon and @Jubobs for the link. I had a feeling it was a leftover habit from another language or some kind of nonsense... That just confirmed it. The script that I was referring to makes ample use of `-z` and `-n` so it just confounded me even more.

Comment: It's not relevant to whether they have "-z", because there's no such thing. Rather, it guards against empty tokens on one side of the comparison operator.

Comment: Jubobs' link is adequate (and one of many pages offering advice).  However, the [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) is authoritative, and comments on the problem of portability where one of the operands may be a *[null string](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html#tag_20_128_16)*.

Comment: The standard mentions reliability on historical systems in regards to that construct. Is "historical" 25 years ago, as Blue Moon mentioned? Is `[ x"$var" = "$var" ]` (or the test equivalent) a pattern that should be perpetuated or is it safe to eradicate it from my scripts? I'm really only concerned about modern Linux and perhaps BSD utilities.

Comment: More than null strings are problematic here as the links from Thomas Dickey indicate. An argument that starts with `-` or `! ` can be misinterpreted by some shells (especially if `"$var"` is unquoted).

Comment: @EtanReisner I tried a few variations starting with `-` `!` `(` `)` and didn't encounter any issues. Of course I used quotes as I always do with test, so I'm not really worried about the oddities that may occur without them. I think the question still remains, is it reasonable to banish `[ x"$var" = x"$var" ]` for modern versions of test? It seems so.

Comment: Yes, I believe for modern shells on most systems that can be banished to the dustbin of history. I don't have a good sense of whether even recent Solaris/etc. systems might have a vulnerable shell by default though (they might even though I would dearly hope not).

Comment: Even Solaris has a Posix shell available, even if it's not the default shell. I would document that your script requires a POSIX-compliant shell to execute, and let anyone using an archaic shell file a bug report.

Answer (score 1):

See [Which `[` can not compare empty strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35365744/5512755)

It is an old fashioned way to test is a variable is empty or does not exist.