# Which `[` can not compare empty strings?

Tags: sh

In some ancient Shell scripts for Solaris I found the following notation to check if a variable is empty:

```
[ x"$var" = x ]
```

On a current Linux system I would write it just as

```
[ "$var" = "" ]
```

or

```
[ -z "$var" ]
```

Which version of `[` actually requires the first notation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None.The alias from [] to test appears after the option -z of test. Therefore, if you can use `[ x"$var" = x]`, you can also write `[ -z "$var" ]`.

Comment: @ceving To avoid problems with unsafe implementations, if you test some strings like "-o a=a". See http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/test/